# Password must be at least 6 characters Firebase error in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am at my wits end. Code that worked before now stops working with no changes made. Main issue is with Firebase throwing error that password must be at least 6 characters. However, I have a validation of at least 8 characters on the password form field that is correctly validated before passing the value to the account registration module. That's when Firebase returns the error of "password must be at least 6 chars". How could this be; especially when this worked before and was able to create new users? Now I can no longer create an account. Here are the relevant code snippets and I thank you for your help.

Registration module:

```
 Future<User?> register(
    context,
     String name,
     String phone,
     String email,
     String password,
    String mediaUrl,
  ) async {
    var date = DateTime.now().toString();
    var parsedDate = DateTime.parse(date);
    var formattedDate =
        '${parsedDate.month}/${parsedDate.day}/${parsedDate.year}';
  

    try {
      await _read(firebaseAuthProvider).createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email.toLowerCase().trim(),
        password: password.trim(),
      );
      final User? user = _read(firebaseAuthProvider).currentUser;
      final _uid = user!.uid;

      await _read(firebaseFirestoreProvider).collection('users').doc(_uid).set(
        {
          'id': _uid,
          'name': name,
          'phone': phone,
          'email': email,
          'mediaUrl': '',
          'joinedDate': formattedDate,
          // 'createdAt': Timestamp.now(),
        },
      );
      Navigator.canPop(context) ? Navigator.pop(context) : null;
      // .then((value) =>
      //     Navigator.canPop(context) ? Navigator.pop(context) : null);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      throw CustomException(message: e.message);
    }
  }
```

The form part relevant to password:

```
 TextFormField(
    key: const ValueKey('password'),
    controller: _passwordController,
    focusNode: _passwordFocusScope,
    // onEditingComplete: _submit,
    onEditingComplete: () => FocusScope.of(context)
        .requestFocus(_confirmFocusScope),
    obscureText: _isVisible.value,
    validator: (value) {
      if (value!.isEmpty || value.length < 8) {
        return 'Password cannot be empty and must be at least 8 chars!';
      }
      return null;
    },
    onSaved: (value) {
      _password = value!.trim();
    },
    textInputAction: _authMode.value == AuthMode.register
        ? TextInputAction.next
        : TextInputAction.done,
    onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
      FocusScope.of(context)
          .requestFocus(_confirmFocusScope);
    },
    decoration: kTextInputDecoration.copyWith(
      labelText: 'Password',
      labelStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: Device.screenType == ScreenType.mobile
            ? 16.sp
            : 18.sp,
      ),
      filled: true,
      fillColor: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
      prefixIcon: Icon(
        Icons.lock,
        size: Device.screenType == ScreenType.mobile
            ? 4.w
            : 6.w, //30,
      ),
      suffixIcon: IconButton(
        icon: _isVisible.value
            ? Icon(
                Icons.visibility_off,
                size: Device.screenType == ScreenType.mobile
                    ? 3.w
                    : 4.w, //30,
              )
            : Icon(
                Icons.visibility,
                size: Device.screenType == ScreenType.mobile
                    ? 3.w
                    : 4.w, //30,
              ),
        onPressed: () {
          _isVisible.value = !_isVisible.value;
        },
      ),
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
    ),
  ),
  SizedBox(
    height: 1.8.h, //10,
  ),
  if (_authMode.value == AuthMode.register)
    TextFormField(
      focusNode: _confirmFocusScope,
      // controller: _passwordController,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
      // onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
      //   FocusScope.of(context)
      //       .requestFocus(_confirmFocusScope);
      // },
      // onEditingComplete: FocusScope.of(context)
      //     .unfocus(),
      key: const ValueKey('confirm'),
      obscureText: _isVisible.value,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value != _passwordController.text) {
          return 'Passwords do not match!';
        }
        return null;
      },
      decoration: kTextInputDecoration.copyWith(
        labelText: 'Confirm Password',
        labelStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: Device.screenType == ScreenType.mobile
              ? 16.sp
              : 18.sp,
        ),
        filled: true,
        fillColor: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
        prefixIcon: Icon(
          Icons.lock,
          size: Device.screenType == ScreenType.mobile
              ? 4.w
              : 6.w, //30,
        ),
        suffixIcon: IconButton(
          icon: _isVisible.value
              ? Icon(
                  Icons.visibility_off,
                  size:
                      Device.screenType == ScreenType.mobile
                          ? 3.w
                          : 3.5.w, //30,
                )
              : Icon(
                  Icons.visibility,
                  size:
                      Device.screenType == ScreenType.mobile
                          ? 3.w
                          : 4.w, //30,
                ),
          onPressed: () {
            _isVisible.value = !_isVisible.value;
          },
        ),
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      ),
    ),
  SizedBox(
    height: 1.8.h, //10,
  ),
  MyButton(
    text: _authMode.value == AuthMode.login
        ? 'Login'
        : 'Sign Up',
    txtColor: Colors.white,
    txtSize: Device.screenType == ScreenType.mobile
        ? 19.sp
        : 24.sp,
    bgColor: Colors.deepPurple,
    onTap: () {
      FocusScope.of(context)
          .unfocus(); // used to dismiss the keyboard
      // _submit();
      final _isValid = _formKey.currentState!.validate();
      if (_isValid) {
        _formKey.currentState?.save();
        _formKey.currentState?.reset();
        _authMode.value == AuthMode.login
            ? ref
                .read(authRepositoryProvider)
                .login(context, _email, _password)
            : ref.read(authRepositoryProvider).register(
                  context,
                  _name,
                  _email,
                  _password,
                  _mediaUrl,
                  _phone,
                );
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
            context, BottomNavScreen.routeName);
      }
    },
  ),
```

Referenced providers:

```
final storageRefProvider = Provider<FirebaseStorage>((ref) => FirebaseStorage.instance);
final firebaseAuthProvider =
    Provider<FirebaseAuth>((ref) => FirebaseAuth.instance);
final firebaseFirestoreProvider =
    Provider<FirebaseFirestore>((ref) => FirebaseFirestore.instance);
```

[SignUp Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yr5me.png)

Answer (score 2):

This means that the password must be at least 6 characters long. Please read [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException).

Comment: I understand the error says but doesn't make sene since I am already ensuring that the supplied password is at least 8 chars long via code (see the relevant form validation section of the form). Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the passed positional parameters and the returned value are out of order. Parameters are called in the following order: name, phone, email, password, and mediaUrl. But when the register function is called from the register button, the phone value is passed after the email, which I think screwed up the value returned by the password (most likely a null value from mediaUrl . This solved the problem.)

However, another issue surfaced "using the null operator for null values", which doesn't affect user creation. But look where this error comes from. Thanks!